# Display @odata property or index value with PHP from JSON

Tags: php, json, odata

Using PHP and I have JSON from a URL that looks like this:

```
{
  "@odata.count": 66547,
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.context": "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/actris/$metadata#PropertyUnitType",
      "@odata.id": "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/actris/PropertyUnitType('51e19b6486d3d28a7cf543d5efafc534')",
      "ACTRIS_NumHalfBaths": 1,
    }
  ]
}
```

My PHP code is this:

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/actris/PropertyUnitTypes?access_token=TOKEN';

$jsonb = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonbtrue = json_decode($jsonb,true);
$jsonbfalse = json_decode($jsonb);
$nextlink = $jsonbtrue['@odata.nextLink'];
$valuedata = $jsonbfalse->value;

echo "Search results are: $nextlink";

foreach($valuedata as $datavalue):
    echo $datavalue->ACTRIS_NumHalfBaths;
    echo $datavalue['@odata.id'];
endforeach;

?>
```

I can't figure out how to get `@odata.id` to display.  If I remove it from the PHP code the `ACTRIS_NumHlafBaths` appear just fine.  If I try to echo the `@odata.id` I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I can display the `@odata.count` just fine because it is not nested and not in a  loop.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$jsonbtrue` that's an array and `$jsonbfalse` that's an object.  For an object that is an invalid property name so you need [Complex (curly) Syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
echo $jsonbfalse->value[0]->{'@odata.id'};
```

For an array:

```
echo $jsonbtrue['value'][0]['@odata.id'];
```

Since your `$datavalue` is an object:

```
foreach($valuedata as $datavalue):
    echo $datavalue->ACTRIS_NumHalfBaths;
    echo $datavalue->{'@odata.id'};
endforeach;
```

If you stick with just using the array then you don't have to worry about what parts are arrays and what parts are objects and you won't have to worry about the invalid property names:

```
foreach($jsonbtrue['value'] as $datavalue):
    echo $datavalue['ACTRIS_NumHalfBaths'];
    echo $datavalue['@odata.id'];
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I couldn't quite figure this one out as PHP is new to me.  Your solution works perfectly.